# R - Delete unique rows in "neighborhood"

Tags: r, duplicates, unique, vectorization

I have input data in the below format

```
 stress word
 0      hello
 1      hello
 1      this
 1      is
 1      a
 1      normal
 0      normal
 1      test
 1      hello
```

I want to get output as

```
stress  word       stress_pos
 0      hello      2
 1      hello      2
 1      normal     1
 0      normal     1
```

The dataset is a large list with words indicating the position of a word's stress -- if the k^th row containing a word is a 1 in the first column then the stress is placed on the k^th syllable. Words may appear in multiple places in the list, so I would like to remove non-duplicates in the range of 3 rows (for each row look at the previous and the next line). I'm only dealing with disyllabic words. That is why I'm only looking at the direct neighbors.

I can't use `duplicated()` or `unique()` (or I don't know how) because they would process the whole table and not only a small part of it.

The third column indicates what the position of the stress in the word is which can be derived from column one.

Is there any way to not use loops? And what would be a good way to go about this?

Comment: Honestly I still can't figure out the output and how it got there. What is a `stress_pos`, and how is it summed up?

Comment: you're saying helló and not héllo.
so in hello the stress is at the second position. therefore everywhere under `stress_pos` you have a 2 for hello. and the second hello has a 1 under `stress` because the second syllable is stressed

Comment: So why is there are 2 in `stress_pos` in the first row for the output? How did you calculate the 2?

Comment: there is a 2 in the first row because hello has a stress at the second position. for the same reason there is a 2 in the second row.

Comment: Fine, but how did you figure out that hello has a stress at the second position based on your raw data?

Comment: first row has a 0 under stress. so first syllable is not stressed. second row has a 1 so the second syllable is stressed

Comment: I'm stumped. Nothing you've written makes any sense to me.  Best of luck...I hope someone else can help.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I'll try to further explain this:
The single-syllabic words are basically errors in my data. If they are filtered by deleting the unique words they won't be a problem anymore (I guess for these words the stress-numbers don't make much sense). What is left then are the words that occure in pairs. For them you have boolean values. If for a 2-syllabic word the first row is 0 then the first syllable is not stressed. If for this word the second row is 0 the second syllable is not stressed. So first row is for the first syllable, second one is for the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's consider how to remove all words that are not duplicated by another word within distance 3 of them. You could determine whether each word matches the word with difference `d` from it with:

```
matches <- function(words, d) {
  words <- as.character(words)
  if (d < 0) {
    words == c(rep("", -d), head(words, d))
  } else {
    words == c(tail(words, -d), rep("", d))
  }
}
```

Then you could grab the appropriate rows of your data with:

```
(out <- dat[rowSums(sapply(c(-1, 1), function(d) matches(dat$word, d))) > 0,])
#   stress   word
# 1      0  hello
# 2      1  hello
# 6      1 normal
# 7      0 normal
```

All the remains is to determine the syllable that is stressed:

```
out$word <- as.character(out$word)
out$stress_pos <- ave(out$stress, out$word, FUN=function(x) min(which(x == 1)))
out
#   stress   word stress_pos
# 1      0  hello          2
# 2      1  hello          2
# 6      1 normal          1
# 7      0 normal          1
```